# Passport js How to save the user in the session?

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, express-session

I want to have access to my user in `req.user` which is supposed to be stored in the session. Here is my server js code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const socketIO = require("socket.io");

const http = require("http");
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socketIO(server);

const router = require("express-promise-router")();
const cors = require("cors");
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const validator = require("express-validator");
const session = require("express-session");
const MongoStore = require("connect-mongo")(session);
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const passport = require("passport");
const keys = require("./config/keys");

//import cloudinary
require("./services/cloudinaryUpload");
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb://localhost/chat-app",
  { useNewUrlParser: true },
  () => console.log("Connected to Mongo Server")
);

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

//require the models
require("./models/users.js");
require("./models/groups.js");


//require passport
require("./services/passport");
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "thisisasecretkey",
    resave: true,
    saveInitialized: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    store: new MongoStore({ mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection })
  })
);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(router);

//Require sockets
require("./sockets/groupchat")(io);

app.set("trust proxy", 1);

//Require routes
require("./routes/users")(router);
require("./routes/admin")(router);
require("./routes/home")(router);
require("./routes/group")(router);

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.use(validator());

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Server is listening on the port 5000");
});
```

Here is my passport js code:

```
const passport = require("passport");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const User = mongoose.model("users");
const LocalStrategy = require("passport-local").Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require("passport-facebook").Strategy;
const GoogleStrategy = require("passport-google-oauth20").Strategy;
const keys = require("../config/keys");

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    console.log("passport has deserialized the user", user);
    done(null, user);
  } catch (error) {
    done(error, null);
  }
});


passport.use(
  new FacebookStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.facebook.clientID,
      clientSecret: keys.facebook.clientSecret,
      profileFields: ["email", "displayName", "photos"],
      callbackURL: "/api/auth/facebook/callback",
      passReqToCallback: true,
      proxy: true
    },
    async (req, token, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ facebook: profile.id });
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        }
        const newUser = new User();
        newUser.facebook = profile.id;
        newUser.fullname = profile.displayName;
        newUser.email = profile._json.email;
        newUser.userImage = `https://graph.facebook.com/${
          profile.id
        }/picture?type=large`;
        newUser.fbTokens.push({ token });
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        done(null, savedUser);
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: keys.google.clientID,
      clientSecret: keys.google.clientSecret,
      profileFields: ["email", "displayName", "photos"],
      callbackURL: "/api/auth/google/callback",
      passReqToCallback: true,
      proxy: true
    },
    async (req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ google: profile.id });
        if (user) {
          return done(null, user);
        }
        const newUser = new User();
        newUser.google = profile.id;
        newUser.fullname = profile.displayName;
        newUser.email = profile.emails[0].value;
        newUser.userImage = profile._json.image.url;
        const savedUser = await newUser.save();
        done(null, savedUser);
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err, false);
      }
    }
  )
);
module.exports = passport;
```

I have a get User route and want to send the user but it is not working:

```
  router.get("/api/get-user", (req, res) => {
    if (req.user) {
      return res.status(200).send(req.user);
    }
    return res.status(401).send({ message: "The user does not exist" });
  });
```

Comment: Is `deserializeUser` being called? If so, what is its result? Also, you're calling `passport.initialize()` twice, and it looks like you're mounting `cookieParser` and `validator` too late.

Comment: @robertklep deserializeUser is called once only during authentication. It does have the full user. I have updated the code which is still not working.

Comment: @robertklep Can you tell me why is this happening?

Comment: @robertklep does deserializeUser should be called on every request?

Comment: Yes, `deserializeUser` should be called for every request (after a user has logged in). If it doesn't get called, it can mean that the session cookie has expired, or the route handler (for `/api/get-user`) isn't mounted in the correct place (too early, before the session and Passport middleware).

Comment: @robertklep it is only called when I click on log in via google. (before I am shown the sign up page)

Comment: In that case, start checking each step of the process: does the Google strategy handled get called, does it find an existing user or does it create a new one, is `serializeUser` getting called (which serializes the user data so it can be used in a session), does the session data get stored in MongoDB, is a session cookie being set? Etc.

Comment: @robertklep Upon more analysis, I found that it is being called only on those routes which have passport.authenticate middleware. But it is not working for any other routes. In the route with passport.authenticate middleware it has the full user information

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182638/discussion-between-unity-hour-and-robertklep).